# Can model.CharField data entries be treated as lists in Django?

Tags: for-loop, django-views, django-templates

I have a Django model that contains a field:

```
fruits = models.CharField(verbose_name="Fruits", max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
```

I add data to this field in the form of comma-separated strings, e.g. apple, pear, orange, persimmon.
Django treats the data as a single string, that is 'apple, pear, orange, persimmon', but I'd like to have a way of iterating over these data.  As such, I'd like the string to be a list of the items.  Can this be made explicit at the Model level (e.g. ListField if it exists) or can I do something in views prior to displaying the output in a table in a Django template?

Comment: Use another model with a `ForeignKey` to the model you are working with.

Comment: Yes, thanks Willem, that's an interesting idea.  I assume it would mean I can't input the data using the same Django form, though, right? My real world project actually uses citation id's (in place of fruit), which are from another model (i.e. Reference).  The reason I did it this way is because there are not many of these citation id's compared to the objects they refer to (30-to-hundreds type relationship).  This turned out to be the easier method for me, but now I'm seeing its limitations.

Comment: usually you do *database normalization*, and thus store the `Reference`/`Fruit`s in another table with a `ForeignKey` to the `Citation`s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization this also will make it easier to later search, aggregate, filter, etc.